# Check for incoming SMS in a certain amount of time

Tags: android, timeout, sms

I am new to Android development and I am developing an app that communicates with a remote GSM phone via SMS. I have been able to send the SMS request from Android to the remote phone.

Now what I would like to do is to check if the remote phone sends back an SMS within 20 seconds. Within this 20s, if the SMS is received the app will immediately proceeds to processing the data sent via SMS, otherwise it will give the user a timeout notification.

I have read the documentation on BroadcastReceiver but it seems that the system only allows about 10s before it kills the receiver. Also there doesn't seem to be a way to kill the receiver as soon as the SMS is received.

I am pretty clueless as to how this can be done.

Comment: there must be some solution..

Comment: use an AlarmManager to trigger the timeout.

Comment: the 10 second for your process to be done when you receive the broadcast, it's actually to prevent UI from freezing. your broadcast rceiver will never get killed unless you kill the app or you explicitly unregister it. 
BroadcastReceiver is the best solution for you, but you need to start timer or something when you send the SMS, and then wait the broadcast receiver to tell you if the remote respond to you

Comment: you wrote "Also there doesn't seem to be a way to kill the receiver ... " you mean you registered the receiver in the manifest and you want to deactivate it programmatically ?  i run into the same problem. i found no solution. my workaround to "remember" the situation for example with sharedpreferences and to terminate immediately. if there is an other way it would be nice to read.